# MySQL сортировка части результата

Tags: сортировка, mysql

В процессе создания удобного интерфейса для базы данных возникла необходимость сортировать записи, но сортировать не все сразу, а лишь те, которые попадают на страницу. Страницы создаются с помощью LIMIT. Поясню: есть 5 страниц результатов, пользователь находится на 3-ей странице (`SELECT * FROM`table`LIMIT 200,100`), хотелось бы дать ему возможность, кликнув по заголовку таблички результатов отсортировать записи только на этой странице. Если просто приписать в запрос ORDER BY `field`, то на страницу попадут уже абсолютно другие записи. Понимаю, что можно все сделать уже в PHP, но полей, по которым можно производить сортировку 7 штук, включая дату, с которой не хочется возиться. Буду благодарен, если подскажете, как этого избежать.

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
select field1, field2 
from (
  select field1, field2 
  from tab
  order by field1
  limit 200,100
) x
order by field2 desc
```

А по поводу сортировки на клиенте подумайте еще раз. дату можно timestamp'ом передавать, все будет замечательно сравниваться и быстрее притом.

Comment: Спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 1):

Сортируйте результаты уже на стороне клиента, не насилуйте БД.

Например [jqxGrid](http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm)

Comment: это не совсем тот вариант, что в вопросе. грид сортирует все записи, а надо только отображаемые. нужен самописный механизм, но на клиенте, да.